# Vimeo vid in fancybox - playing only the first time

Tags: jquery, fancybox, vimeo

I have a fancybox for inline item that contains a vimeo video ebmedded by iframe. when i first trigger the fancybox - no problem. but after i close it and try open again - no video.

i have to use inline because of the design of the fancybox requires some elements.

this is the code for the inline box:

```
<div style="display:none"><div id="fb-wrapper"  class="simple">
      <img src="http://www.xxxxxxx.com/homestuff/images/window-fb-right-2903.png" id="right-window-fb" />
      <img src="http://www.xxxxxxxx.com/homestuff/images/window-fb-left-2903.png" id="left-window-fb" />
      <iframe id="player_1" src="http://player.vimeo.com/video/xxxxxx?title=0&amp;byline=0&amp;portrait=0&amp;autoplay=1&amp;api=1&amp;player_id=player_1" width="480" height="240" frameborder="0" webkitAllowFullScreen mozallowfullscreen allowFullScreen></iframe>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Most likely you are using fancybox v1.3.4, aren't you?

Regarding the `iframe`, there is a bug and a workaround that you can [learn more about here](http://groups.google.com/group/fancybox/browse_thread/thread/feec524b4c0199bc)

Additionally, since you are using `inline` content, there is another bug that you need to be aware of ... and [here you will find the description and the workaround](http://groups.google.com/group/fancybox/browse_thread/thread/fab7b6d81a173b33)

From my point of view, it's a bad idea to have hidden inline iframes because they will create an overhead in your page load regardless that they are visible or not.

In you case I would target the video directly and set the fancybox `type` to `iframe`

Comment: thanks for the tips. i'm not sure it's possible for me to have type iframe because i need a background behind and images beside the vimeo video. how can it be done with just iframe? this is what i'm working on: http://www.israelinsidethemovie.com/new-homepage/

Comment: you can keep doing it the way you do, but the first bug is what makes the video to display the first time only. In that case apply the workaround, either editing the fancybox js file or follow the instructions here http://groups.google.com/group/fancybox/browse_thread/thread/d7321b9a4df5b20b/